# How to check is incumbent settings object tracking working in the browser

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-next

There is interesting section in the mdn article of Promises and that's it [incumbent settings object tracking](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise#incumbent_settings_object_tracking). But the most interesting at the end, there is written:

> In the above example, the inner text of the  will be updated only if the incumbent settings object is tracked. This is because without tracking the incumbent, we may end up using the wrong environment to send the message.

The problem is that it is not correct example, because iframes loading asynchronously and in some cases in firefox, example won't be work too. So I want to see correct example that prove that the [only firefox support this feature](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_builtins_promise_incumbent_settings_object_tracking).

What will be example of the incumbent settings tracking that proving working conception in firefox and vica versa with others browsers?

Comment: Appears to have been added [here](https://github.com/mdn/sprints/issues/3495), and nobody understands it… Which is also why it's [going to be removed from the spec](https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/1430). There's a big bold [warning in the spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-incumbent-everything) saying that the incumbent concept is "*excessively complicated and unintuitive to work with.*"

Comment: @Bergi I saw it all. This is confusing me, hate undeterminacy. But anyway I should have hear it from expert in this field. By the way you don't understand this conception too? Don't you?

Comment: Tbh I've never heard of it. I'm just reading the html spec, the three examples given there do a good job of explaining what it's meant to do and why. Not sure how that translates to the example in the MDN promises page; either way I think it's very confusing to put that stuff in the MDN promises documentation. Imo it should focus on promises, not cross-realm call intricacies.

Comment: Is this question related to https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/7903?

Comment: @Bergi I got you. How I noticed incumbent in promises it is more about interaction others web-API. Placement in promises is just an intermediate step that supports this concept for other mechanisms. Something like that.

Comment: @Bergi yeah, the question is a little dirty, as there are too many questions to understand a specific thing. Caught me :)

Comment: "*iframes loading asynchronously*" - did you try just placing the code in an `iframe.onload` handler? This seems to be used in the html spec examples, and shouldn't affect incumbent tracking afaics, so it might fix the MDN example as well. What outputs do you get when running the code in Firefox vs Chrome?

Comment: @Bergi no matter will you place code into `setTimeout` or into `iframe.onload` result will be same (converting callback to web-IDL structure maintane this, it saves callback context in there). Recently I created [example for demonstrating that to show what handlers in `then` works fine in the most browsers not only in firefox](https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-agnesi-v00rqg).